# How I can solve this circuit with diodes?

Tags: diodes, short-circuit

I tried to solve this circuit but without success.. Also is there any current flowing trough D3? and how this isn't short circuit?

[image]

Comment: In reality this would be a basically be short-circuit with any real voltage supply, but the voltage source here is very tiny and around the knee region so nothing blows up. In this state, the diode is more of non-linear resistor (where voltage across the diode depends on current) than an ideal diode.

Comment: Have you heard of the Shockley Diode Equation?

Comment: Yes i heard but how I can solve this when i don't have current flowing and also don't have voltage of diode? Tried to find relationship between two but failed..

Comment: Hint: add the Shockley diode equation to your question by **editing** it and apply it to any of the diodes to get a start.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you expand your hint.. :P I tried Is3 = Id3, results are off.. If there is no current Id3 = 0 then I get from Shockley diode equation that U3 is also 0..

Comment: My hint was very much that you **edit** your question to include the equation, but now someone else has already answered with the equation, so we go by their notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know the Shockley diode equation:

$$I_\text{D}=I_\text{SAT}\left(e^{^\frac{V_\text{D}}{\eta\,V_T}}-1\right)$$

Since the emission coefficient, \$\eta\$, isn't specified we can assume it is \$\eta=1\$ and simplify a bit (or you can keep it in, if you want.) Here, I'll ignore it.

The only voltage you need to compute is the common node shared by all three diodes (unlabeled in your diagram.) Let's call it \$V_\text{X}\$. Then nodal analysis says that the sum of the currents into the node must equal the currents out of the node. So it's easy to set up the following (since \$I_{\text{SAT}_1}=I_{\text{SAT}_2}\$, I'm just replacing any instance of \$I_{\text{SAT}_2}\$ with \$I_{\text{SAT}_1}\$ below):

$$\begin{align*}
I_{\text{SAT}_1}\left(e^{^\frac{V_\text{X}}{V_T}}-1\right)+I_{\text{SAT}_3}\left(e^{^\frac{-V_\text{X}}{V_T}}-1\right)&=I_{\text{SAT}_1}\left(e^{^\frac{65\:\text{mV}-V_\text{X}}{V_T}}-1\right)\\\\
e^{^\frac{V_\text{X}}{V_T}}+\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}\cdot e^{^\frac{-V_\text{X}}{V_T}}-\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}&=e^{^\frac{65\:\text{mV}}{V_T}}\cdot e^{^\frac{-V_\text{X}}{V_T}}\\\\
\left(e^{^\frac{V_\text{X}}{V_T}}\right)^2-\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}\cdot e^{^\frac{V_\text{X}}{V_T}}+\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}&=e^{^\frac{65\:\text{mV}}{V_T}}
\end{align*}$$

Set \$y=e^{^\frac{V_\text{X}}{V_T}}\$ and the above becomes this quadratic:

$$y^2+\left(-\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}\right)y+\left(\frac{I_{\text{SAT}_3}}{I_{\text{SAT}_1}}-e^{^\frac{65\:\text{mV}}{V_T}}\right)=0$$

Solve that for \$y\$ (pick the reasonable one of the two answers) and then find \$V_\text{X}=V_T\,\operatorname{ln}\:y\$. (I think in your situation \$V_T\approx 25\:\text{mV}\$, but feel free to use whatever you think is appropriate there.)